# How does Facebook verifies mobile apps

Tags: android, facebook, hash, oauth, key

Assume that you build a native android app which uses Facebook login. For that first you have to build a Facebook app and configure Package Name, Class Name, Key Hashes of your android app. I assume the authenticity of app is validated through this Key hash. but the problem is after we configure this key in Facebook app, we never configure it in our mobile app or send it to Facebook when we make API calls. So how does the Facebook validates that this is the original app which is making the API call?

Comment: really, i guess the `.apk` file generated is always signed with`debug.keystore` keys.

Comment: Not according to what I found by Googling. You have to sign with a different private key when you release the app

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you put an app onto a device (whether via eclipse/IntelliJ or by building a .apk) you're signing it with a key. When you log in via Facebook using SSO, the native Facebook app can get the signature of the calling app, and passes it to the server to get verified.

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply. But what if I don't have the native Facebook app installed on my android device, then how does the Facebook server receives the signature of my app?

Comment: It doesn't, but then you don't get an SSO access token, which is longer lived. See the differences between short-term and long-term tokens here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Comment: I see. So if I know a fb app id of an app which was created by someone, I could just use that in my mobile app to get a short lived access token to access user information (I don't need to create a fb app for my mobile app). Am I correct?

Comment: You forget that the user still has to authorize you. Presumably if your app is FOO, and they see on the authorization page app BAR, they will know something is up. The user can also deauthorize any app at any time.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for answering my question. I guess I got what I need. Thanks once again.