# Facebook KeyHashes verification in android

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I am using facebook sdk to request the fb login in my android app.

From what I figured out after reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23985965/how-does-facebook-verify-app-authenticity-with-key-hash), if I have a native fb client installed on my device, than that client gets the signature of my app and then verifies it(or sends it to the server that verifies this) with the key hashes that I have uploaded on my facebook app page.

Now, if I don't have the native facebook app installed, how does it still verifies the same?

I can see a method named `setupAppCallForWebFallbackDialog` in the `ServerProtocol` class which calculates the key hash of the current package and passes it to the web dialog.

Now, we know that we can get the signature of any package in android in any app using `PacakgeManager`.

So, if I clone the facebook sdk from [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) and then hardcode it to calculate the signature of a particular app and I am using that app's application id in my project, can I ask the user to login on that app's behalf? Am I missing something here?