# How to send sensitive data from one app to another in android

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography, sharedpreferences

Referring to my previous question

[PREVIOUS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60634550/encryption-in-sending-data-from-one-app-to-another-in-android)

> How I can share the secure data from one app to another?

My both apps are in production already, so would I be able to use SharedUserID as it requires signing with same certificate?

> **Please don't refer my own question as an answer**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encryption in sending data from one app to another in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60634550/encryption-in-sending-data-from-one-app-to-another-in-android)

Comment: @VivekMishra That question posted by me only. I have referred its link as well in this question

Comment: Still it is the same question and you should ask your further doubts in that same question. Asking it again doesn't does any good .

Comment: The context is different (using sharedUserId). I thought asking a new question will be good instead of creating long thread. Hope you understand.

Comment: At least review the documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html which states that `android:sharedUserId` is **deprecated in API level 29**.

Comment: What's wrong with a normal explicit Intent?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by followings.

1) Deep linking
2) AIDL